# read.table in R is not reading all columns

Tags: r

I had posted before a question related to this, but the solutions didn´t solve completely my problem.

I have a table that contains the characters "'", and "#" and when I read it using read.table() to read it and it cannot skip the rows that contain those characters.

I am reading the file using the command:

```
table<- read.table("table.txt",header =TRUE, sep ="\t",quote="'",skip=8,fill=TRUE, comment.char="#",check.names=F)
```

This is only reading the first column of the table and not the entire table like it was supposed to do, any suggestions how to solve this? 
[image]

An example line of the table containing # is:

```
Homo sapiens    Unigene Hs.549823   ILMN_110080 HS.549823   Hs.549823       Hs.549823       5053715 AI732602            ILMN_1846799    5910129 S   320 GCAGGTTGTTATTGTTGCTGAGCGGGGTGTGTGGGTGGCTAACGAGAGGG  11  +   61276241-61276290       zo26g12.x5 Stratagene colon (#937204) Homo sapiens cDNA clone IMAGE:588070 3, mRNA sequence
```

Comment: Please show us `table.txt`, without it we need to be psychic to solve your problem...

Comment: Just added a part of the table to the post

Comment: Don't see the sample.  Meanwhile, try creating some sample files of your own, one or 2 lines per file, and see what the offending line is.

Comment: I dont know which line is it, because it only reads the 1st column of the table, it seems that all the other columns are ignored,

Comment: I think you want to use `quote="", comment=""` rather than `quote="'", comment.char="#"` (as answered in previous question)

Comment: open the txt file in any text editor and show us how it looks like (not the table format).

Comment: Better yet, if you can host a text file with a subset of your data on a dropbox public folder, we can test solutions on the real thing.

Comment: I think now I was able to read the entire table, by using quote="", comment="", but i still to check it manually if it worked properly.

Comment: @BenBolker Won't comment.char cause everything after the `#` to be ignored?

Comment: ?? that's why I suggested `comment.char=""` to turn off comments completely (actually I said `comment=""`, but partial argument matching should take care of that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `readLines()` instead to get the raw lines, then splice them according to your delimiter

```
library(stringr)

# Open Connection to file
pathToFile <- path.expand("~/path/to/file/myfile.txt")
f <- file(pathToFile, "rb")  

# Read in lines
rawText <- readLines(f)

problemFreeTable <- 
  sapply(rawText, str_split, "\t")  # replace "\t" with "," or the appropriate delim.
```